# Regex matching in street name vs street type

Tags: regex

Currently I have my regex to separate out an address into different groups. The issue I am facing is when no street type exists at the end of the address and a match occurs in the street name.

For example, included in my search for street type is the word "ridge". The address "123 Cambridge Bay" matches "camb" as the street name and "ridge" as the street type when really there shouldnt be a match for street type. Only street name as "Cambridge Bay"

Regex:

```
(\d+).*?((?:[a-z](?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+)).*?((?:court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|road|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trail|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw)).*?((?:UNT|\#)[^\S\r\n]?\w|\w.*)?$|(\d+).*?((?:[a-z](?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+))$
```

Simply adding "123 cambridge bay dr" works fine

You can see this working here

[Testing](https://regex101.com/r/h3LYzN/8)

Comment: You need a whitespace before the street type, like: `(\d+).*?((?:[a-z](?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+)).*?(\w+(?:court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|road|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trail|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw)).*?((?:UNT|\#)[^\S\r\n]?\w|\w.*)?$|(\d+).*?((?:[a-z](?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+))$`

Comment: Try this  https://regex101.com/r/h3LYzN/9